# Prostration during offerings?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, ki-tavo, bikkurim-first-fruits

While the first-fruits were being offered, it is stated in *Deuteronomy 26:10* that after the declaration of the person offering, they would "prostrate themselves before Hashem."

**Where would they prostrate themselves towards, and how?**

Also, is this the only offering in which the person would prostrate themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Ralbag Biur HaMilos](https://www.sefaria.org/Ralbag_Beur_HaMilot_on_Torah%2C_Deuteronomy.26.10.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains this bowing to mean that everyone who enters the Beis HaMikdash (Temple) bows down before G-d and this is next to the Kodesh Kodashim (Holy of Holies)

The [Chizkuni](https://www.sefaria.org/Chizkuni%2C_Deuteronomy.26.10.1-2?lang=bi) adds:

> והשתחוית “you will bow down” - as people do when taking leave of a superior such as a Rabbi.

As to how they would bow, the [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_Deuteronomy.26.10.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) quotes Rambam that the bowing was with the hands and feet